# Is my whole site is blocked by this Disallow: /

Tags: web-crawlers, robots.txt

This is a view of my *robots.txt* file did this query blocked only Baiduspider Search Engine or all of the search engines to check my site.

```
User-agent: Baiduspider
Disallow: /

User-agent: *
Disallow: /templates_c/
```

Answer (score 6):

If you are using `disallow:/` with `user-agent: *` then only entire site is blocked with *robots.txt*.

Otherwise only particular user-agent will get blocked with your sites.

Blocking user-agents:

The `Disallow` line lists the pages you want to block. You can list a specific URL or a pattern. The entry should begin with a forward slash (`/`).

```
To block the entire site, use a forward slash.

Disallow: /

To block a directory and everything in it, follow the directory name with a forward slash.

Disallow: /junk-directory/

To block a page, list the page.

Disallow: /private_file.html

To remove a specific image from Google Images, add the following:

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: /images/dogs.jpg 

To remove all images on your site from Google Images:

User-agent: Googlebot-Image
Disallow: / 

To block files of a specific file type (for example, .gif), use the following:

User-agent: Googlebot
Disallow: /*.gif$

To prevent pages on your site from being crawled, while still displaying AdSense ads on those pages, disallow all bots other than Mediapartners-Google. This keeps the pages from appearing in search results, but allows the Mediapartners-Google robot to analyze the pages to determine the ads to show. The Mediapartners-Google robot doesn't share pages with the other Google user-agents. For example:

User-agent: *
Disallow: /

User-agent: Mediapartners-Google
Allow: /
```

For more details see [this](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en), and user-agents for Google [here](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/1061943?hl=en).

Comment: Thanks dan. That small piece of information means a lot to me thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The [`Baiduspider` bot](http://www.baidu.com/search/spider.htm) is not allowed to crawl anything on your host.

All other bots are not allowed to crawl any URL whose path begins with `/templates_c/`. They may crawl all other URLs on your host.